# Piping sed/grep output does not work

Tags: bash, sed, grep, pipe, io-redirection

If I run the commands bellow, only `out1` has output, the `out2` and `out3` are empty.

```
# this is just to generate a self-signed certificate
openssl genrsa -out /tmp/ssl.key 2048
openssl req -sha256 -new -key /tmp/ssl.key -out /tmp/ssl.csr -subj /CN=localhost
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in /tmp/ssl.csr -signkey /tmp/ssl.key -out /tmp/ssl.crt

# works
openssl s_server -cert /tmp/ssl.crt -key /tmp/ssl.key -accept 444 > out1
# does not work, but if I run without '> out2' it works
openssl s_server -cert /tmp/ssl.crt -key /tmp/ssl.key -accept 446 | sed "s/ACCEPT/ACCEPT445/g" > out2
# does not work, but if I run without '> out3' it works
openssl s_server -cert /tmp/ssl.crt -key /tmp/ssl.key -accept 447 | grep ACCEPT > out3
```

Why does redirecting stdout from sed or grep fail, but running without redirecting works ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `sed -u` (`-l`on BSD/Mac OSX systems), and `grep --line-buffered`options.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to expect the `out2` and `out3` being written in real time, but `sed` and `grep` in pipe wait for the EOF. And nothing fails here.

Kill `openssl` from another console and check if you have correct results in `out2` and `out3`.

Comment: `sed` and `grep` don't wait for the EOF regardless of whether they're in pipes or not; however pipes themselves are buffered.  `sed` and `grep` handle the input as soon as they see it.

Comment: You are correct, killing openssl will have correct results in `out2` and `out3`. How could I go around this without killing openssl?

Comment: Wasn't your original question **why** it did not work?